# Let $G,H$ be two groups. Show that the order of $G$, $|G| = 16$.

Tags: normal-subgroups

Let $G = U(\mathbb{Z}_{32})$ and let $H = \big\{[1],[31]\big\} \leq G$.

(i) Show that $|G| = 16$.

Comment: What does $H$ have to do with $|G|$?

Answer (score 2):

The invertible elements are the odd ones, which of course are exactly $16$. I fail to see the relevance of $H$.

Comment: In general the invertible elements of $\mathbb Z_n$ are those which share no prime factor with $n$.